# Find record with two ids at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conversations, through: :users_conversations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**UsersConversation**

```
class UsersConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Conversation**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :users_conversations
end
```

I need to create query to get the joint conversation between two known users by their ID's. I have this one

```
Conversation.left_joins(:users).where(users: { id: [current_user.id, params[:user_id]]}).first
```

but it finds conversations where is any of `[current_user.id, params[:user_id]]`, so I always get the same conversation, where is `current_user`, but it is wrong. As I see it is because `id: [current_user.id, params[:user_id]]` works like OR, but I need AND. Thank you.

Comment: Does it mean that you need the logic which returns empty collection when `current_user.id` and `params[:user_id]` are different and `user`'s conversations if `current_user.id` and `params[:user_id]` are the same?

Comment: obviously bro if id=[10,11] then id cant be both 10 and 11, it will be either 10 or 11 or something else.

Comment: explain what result you want properly so that we can try to give better solution

Comment: @IgorDrozdov, @krishnar, they can't be the same, only different. I need to check if there is any conversation, that has two associated user records: first with id equal to `current_user.id` and second with id equal to `params[:user_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is not correct as mentioned in the comments. Please do not refer it.**

Try using

```
Conversation.left_joins(:users).find_by("users.id IN(?)", [current_user.id, params[:user_id]]})
```

Haven't actually tried but this should work. Please let me know if you face an error.

Also, use `find_by` instead or `Model.where(condition).first`. Using the latter is a bad habit and convention in rails.

**Explanation**: When you have to find the records where a field matches an array, i.e., you need the value of this filed to be specific from an array, you should use IN operator of SQL. Like

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');`

Comment: @Aakansksha whenever u write Model.where(id: [1,2,4]) , rails will convert array of values like  id IN (1,2,4) only.   You are not doing anything special in your code.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew this. I just checked and you're right abut it. Thanks for pointing it out. I guess you're the down-voter. I would appreciate if you could remove it. I'm going to delete the answer anyways. Will look what could be the other issue here.

Comment: Good to know that you got it.